# Есть ли возможность обернуть аннотацию в свою в Java?

Tags: java, аннотации

Лучше всего объяснить на примере. Допустим в Spring есть аннотация `@RequestMapping`. И у меня есть некий API с кучей контроллеров. Но все контроллеры имеют одинаковый путь. Можно сделать так:

`@RequestMapping(Path.api + "method/")`

Но красивее и интереснее было бы сделать свою аннотацию, скажем `@APIMapping`, которая сама бы вычисляла это выражение `Path.api + value"` и подставляла соответствующую `@RequestMapping`.

А если всё же нельзя так сделать, могу ли я как то сам отловить свою аннотацию и потом приписать нужную (указав `Retention = Source`, чтобы сделать это до запуска приложения)? Или лучше вообще отказаться от этой затеи?

Comment: так что вы конкретно хотите? сделать аннотацию? или добавить префикс?

Comment: Можете сделать свой аннотацию, только retention = Runtime. Регистрация маппингов происходит в рунтайме, а не в исходнике. Вам нужно знать как программно зарегистрировать маппинг в спринге. Составить сканер всех классов/методов для обнаружения всех аннотированных Вашей аннотацией. Этот сканер должен запускаться автоматически по готовности спринга. Значит сканирует он всё, и найдя аннотацию, проводит регистрацию маппинга Path.api + value, где value извлечён из аннотации. Самое сложное здесь - это сканер. А для регистрации маппинга есть соответствующие методы в API спринга. Наверняка.

Comment: Если вдруг не знаете, то для обработки аннотаций во время компиляции (Retention = Source) используется APT - Annotation Processing Tool. Но не знаю можно ли с помощью него добавлять к классу другие аннотации. В крайнем случае можно сгенерить класс с нужными аннотациями, расширяющий исходный.

Comment: На мой взгляд взаимодействовать со спрингом - задача довольно громоздкая.И не стоящего усилий. А вот создание новый классов, может быть тоже громоздким, но зато куда более универсальным способом. Если вместе с IoC контейнером использовать, может быть очень удобно. Каким нибудь Javassist, хотя... Выглядит как стрельба по мухам из пушки )